# How to use ng template let

Tags: angular, ng-template

I have a question about how to use let in ng-template

in my code:

```
ts File

Contact interface = {
id: string
name: string
adresse: string
}

contacts: Contact[]
```

in html

A part of the code

```
<ng-template let-contact = "contacts">
 {{cpntact.name}}
</ng-template>
```

but it does not work.

any ideas?

Comment: `contracts` is an array of `Contract`, meaning multiple of them. Try using an `ng-for`, so that it loops through the contracts. Also note that there's code that doesn't work together. `Contact interface = {` is not the right syntax, and theres a typo in `cpntact` near the `{{ .. }}`

Comment: paste the whole code, because from this it's hard to guess what you want to do really. Also you have a typo here:  {{cpntact.name}}

Comment: share your code with us using a Angular stackblitz instance (https://stackblitz.com/)